# Cannot change font size in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, font

Everywhere I look I see that in order to change the Font size in Xcode I simply click on the "fonts window button".
However, I can't.
I have a default install of Xcode, just started trying to use it the other day.  The fonts window button looks like this:
[image]

Notice how it is grayed out?  Nothing I can figure out will let me click on it to change the font size.  Is this a common problem?  Anyone have a clue how to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to select one or more categories in the list (on the right). [Steps in Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-fonts_and_colors_preferences_help/Recipe.html)

[image]

Comment: Well that was unnecessarily confusing, Xcode design, not your answer just to be clear. Thanks.